# Implementing Secure Data Encryption and Decryption between Frontend and Backend using Public and Private Keys

Tags: python, django, rsa, public-key-encryption, private-key

1. Front end will invoke some API which will provide Public key:
2. Using that public key front end should encrypt it
3. Use the API(POST/PUT) to send the data back.
4. Back end API will decrypt the data using private and public key and store the content.

When the same data is retrieved at front end:

1. Generate the keys and encrypt the data using public key
2. Decrypt the data at front end using the private and public key. what heading can i give for this question

I have three fields which needed to be encrypted and decrypted but I'm only able to encrypt its not decrypting .can u help how to decrypt?

## myapp/utils.py

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
import base64

def encrypt_data(data, public_key_path):
    with open(public_key_path, 'rb') as f:
        public_key = RSA.import_key(f.read())
        cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(public_key)
        encrypted_data = cipher_rsa.encrypt(data.encode('utf-8'))
        return base64.b64encode(encrypted_data).decode('utf-8')

def decrypt_data(encrypted_data, private_key_path):
    encrypted_data = base64.b64decode(encrypted_data)
    with open(private_key_path, 'rb') as f:
        private_key = RSA.import_key(f.read())
        cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key)
        decrypted_data = cipher_rsa.decrypt(encrypted_data)
        return decrypted_data.decode('utf-8')
```

## myapp/views.py

```
def add_candidate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CandidateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            candidate = form.save(commit=False)

            # Encrypt sensitive fields using the public key
            candidate.adharnumber = encrypt_data(candidate.adharnumber, settings.PUBLIC_KEY_PATH)
            candidate.pannumber = encrypt_data(candidate.pannumber, settings.PUBLIC_KEY_PATH)
            candidate.passportnumber = encrypt_data(candidate.passportnumber, settings.PUBLIC_KEY_PATH)

            candidate.save()
            return redirect('candidate_list')
    else:
        form = CandidateForm()
    return render(request, 'candidates/add_candidate.html', {'form': form})

def edit_candidate(request, pk):
    candidate = get_object_or_404(Candidate, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CandidateForm(request.POST, instance=candidate)
        if form.is_valid():
            candidate = form.save(commit=False)

            # Decrypt sensitive fields using the private key
            candidate.adharnumber = decrypt_data(candidate.adharnumber, settings.PRIVATE_KEY_PATH)
            candidate.pannumber = decrypt_data(candidate.pannumber, settings.PRIVATE_KEY_PATH)
            candidate.passportnumber = decrypt_data(candidate.passportnumber, settings.PRIVATE_KEY_PATH)

            candidate.save()
            return redirect('candidate_detail', pk=pk)
    else:
        form = CandidateForm(instance=candidate)
    return render(request, 'candidates/edit_candidate.html', {'form': form, 'candidate': candidate})
```